# Cannot access second field in a 2 dimension array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2 dimension array defined as

```
          var thischart = [[],[]];
```

and the array contains the following data created programatically:

```
    1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10,0,11,0,12,0,13,24,14,0,15,0,16,0,17,0,18,0,19,0,20,0,21,0,22,0,23,0,24,0
```

I cannot get the single value of the second field in the particular array cell.  For example, if I use the following command to get the value:
         alert("thischart[i,1]=" + thischart[0, 1]);

I get the following answer:

```
       thischart[i,1]=2,0
```

I tried using the second dimension to access the data as

```
       thischart[0][1]);
```

but it gives me an error message:

I just want to get the second single value in the array such as for array cell 13 I want the value 24 from above.  Does anyone have an answer on how to access this array?

I populated the array as follows and then updated it thru program logic:

```
       $hours = [];
    for($i = 0; $i< 24; $i++){
      $hours[$i] = [];
      $hours[$i][0] = ($i + 1);
      $hours[$i][1] = "0";

    }
```

And the answer to this question is below:

```
  for(var i in thischart){
     var tc = thischart[i];
      myvalue = tc[1]);   // this is the value I want

  }
```

Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: How do you assign the data to the `thischart` array?

Comment: 2 dimension array exists in javascript...? last time i checked they didn't

Comment: Of course it exists. http://jsfiddle.net/DSrcz/

Comment: `thischart[i,1]=2,0` is not js.

Comment: No its not, but the OP is just echoing that using `alert()` - its not part of his code.

Comment: to answer question i need to know structure of array. can you show how your array looks with data in it. or how it's assigned.

Comment: i think i got it...to do that you would just write thischart[13].

Comment: you don't need to assign numbers to array they are already numbered.

Comment: create a demo with some sample data in jsfiddle.net. Not clear what data looks like...or what error is. Data sample shown is not an array of arrays..it's just a comma separated list of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all of them like this:

```
for(var i in thischart){
  var tc = thischart[i];
  for(var n in tc){
    // n is internal index
    // tc[n] is internal value
  }
}
```

For a single value from the first internal Array, the second value:

```
thischart[0][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the console to see what's the return of

```
thischart[0];
```

Because it should contain an array. If it does, then

```
thischart[0][1];
```

is perfectly valid syntax. And if it doesn't, then

```
thischart[0,1]
```

means nothing whatsoever.

Comment: what about thischart alone?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
alert(items[0][0]); // 1
```

Answer (score -1):

do you mean something like this:...

http://jsfiddle.net/DSrcz/1/

```
var arr = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0];
arr[33]=1000;
alert(arr[13]);
alert(arr[33]);
```

Comment: I populated the array as follows:  $hours = [];
  for($i = 0; $i< 24; $i++){
    $hours[$i] = [];
    $hours[$i][0] = ($i + 1);
    $hours[$i][1] = "0";
    
  }